# Rails: category and subcategory tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hi I am new to rails ... I am trying to make a category and subcategory tree in rails...can you please guide me..

my schema is as follows:

```
create_table "categories", :force => true do |t|
    t.string  "name",   :null => false
    t.string  "aka",    :null => false
    t.integer "parent"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find information here :
http://railscasts.com/episodes/162-tree-based-navigation